Hanging timeout needed
I'm using Firestore and Storage from Firebase.
If I have poor connectivity, the Firestore read aborts automatically and goes to local last saved download - great.
However Storage doesn't seem to follow this. I've tried setting timeout limits but can't see how I implement code when these are triggered:
func getFiles() {        
    // Get a reference to the storage service using the default Firebase App
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    
    // Set time limits in case of poor connection msec
    storage.maxUploadRetryTime = 1
    storage.maxOperationRetryTime = 1
    storage.maxDownloadRetryTime = 1
    
    // Create a storage reference from our storage service
    let storageRef = storage.reference()
    
    // Create a reference to the file we want to download
    let textRef = storageRef.child("/")
    
    var countList = 0

    textRef.listAll { (result, error) in
        for item in result!.items {

If the connection is slow / beyond time limits (which I know I've set very low on purpose as a test) how do I capture has this has triggered and move on? Something like 'maxOperationRetryTime has occurred so do this...'
